# Can multiple list validations happen in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I am working with Share point. I have already written a list validation. Now I need to include another list validation to this.

Both of them are independent of each other.

How can I achieve this?

Plz suggest.

Thanks - vikram

Answer (score 0):

You can only have a validation list. Also you can have a validation for each column. You should try to combine in a single action validation, perhaps combining some logical operations "AND" and "OR". And you should use an error message where all errors are specified.

Something more sophisticated would create event handlers, which will give you more flexibility to validate, but involves development in C # with Visual Studio.

Comment: But I also need different error msgs to display based on condition.

Comment: But SharePoint does not allow more than one validation list. You just have to use an event handler or combined with validations column.